# Get emails that contains attachment using Gmail's API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm trying to get a list of emails that contain attachments,
I'm getting a list of messages, each message contains 2 properties - id and threadID - I assumed that since the messages do not hold an AttachmentID property, they do not have one either.

I didn't find a way to retrieve only messages with attachments.

This is the code:

```
function execute() {
    return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
        "userId": "myid@gmail.com",
        "includeSpamTrash": false,
        "maxResults": 100,
    }).then(function (response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
            },
            function (err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Google documentation - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list , `userId` is path parameter while `q` is query parameter. Putting both `userId` and `q` in the above replies does not work for me.

I can get the following script working in Google Appscript. Before you can call the Gmail API, you will to need to click `Services` on the left hand menu of the Google Appscript Editor --> `Gmail API` --> `Add`. When prompted to authorization, you authorize the code.

```js
function searchMessages() {
  // TODO (developer) - correct the variable to your need
  var userId = 'me';
  try {
    const response = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId, {
      // TODO (developer) - correct the query parameter to fit your need
      'q': 'has:attachment AND filename:csv'
    });
    
    if (!response || !response.messages) {
      console.log('No message');
    } else {
      console.log('Messages:');
      console.log(response);
      for (const message of response.messages ) {
        console.log('- %s', message.id);
        const msgContent = Gmail.Users.Messages.get('me', message.id);
        if (msgContent) {
          // TODO (developer) - Do what you intend to do with the message content
          console.log(msgContent);
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle exception on Messages.list() API
    console.log('Gmail.Users.Messages.list failed with error %s', err.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve only the messages that contains an attachment, you should use the method [`users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) while including a `q` parameter to show only messages with attachments. That `q` parameter can be set up with the string `has:attachment`. On JavaScript that requests looks like the following:

```js
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
      "userId": "{ YOUR USERID HERE }",
      "q": "has:attachment"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

Please remember to update the `userId` parameter to match your own scenario.

## UPDATE

By reading your new comment I understand that your end goal is to retrieve the `attachmentId` field. You can do so very easily just by expanding the above request. You only have to keep in mind that the above function returns a message `id` that can be used to retrieve a [`Message`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message) object containing a [`MessagePart`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#messagepart) inside the `payload` field. That same `MessagePart` object contains a [`MessagePartBody`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments#resource:-messagepartbody) object inside the `body` field. Finally, that `MessagePartBody` contains the `attachmentId` field.

To make it clearer I will describe the process step by step:

1. You run the above [`users.messages.list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) function and get multiple `id` in return.
2. For each `id`, you run a `users.messages.get` function to get a `Message` object. That function can be similar to this example:

```js
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
      "userId": "{ YOUR USERID HERE }",
      "id": "{ THE MESSAGE ID HERE }"
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

3. The step above will return a `Message` object with multiple `MessagePart` inside. Since you are only interested in the attachments `MessagePart` then you need to interact every one of them checking that the `filename` field isn't empty (because only attachments `MessagePart` have a populated `filename` field). Please bear in mind that there is one `MessagePart` per every attachment in the email.
4. Now you have identified which `MessagePart` contains info about the attachment. Finally, you only need to check the `body` property of that `MessagePart`, and read the `attachmentId` field inside.

Comment: I did it, but it still won't retrieve the attachmentid property, which I need in order to access the attachments.

Comment: Hi there @lolshimi11! I have expanded my answer based on your comment. Please give it a look and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function execute() {
  return gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
    "userId": "myid@gmail.com",
    "q": "has:attachment", // This right here
    "includeSpamTrash": false,
    "maxResults": 100,
  })
    .then(
      function (response) {
        // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
        console.log("Response", response);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.error("Execute error", err)
      }
    )
}
```

The "q" parameter has a [horde of options](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) you can use to filter the output. This also works in the Gmail UI.